# Fetch text from Wikipedia randomly

Tags: android, wikipedia

Can we fetch text from Wikipedia randomly? I do not care about the content of the text, the whole I need is to fetch random text whenever I query for the same.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Virat_Kohli&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

The above API gives the result corresponding to the given title (Virat_Kohli), but I do not want to give any title to the API.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a generator with random. Just ommit the title and append this to your query `&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&grnlimit=1`

Example: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=content&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&grnlimit=1